# Xpath OR syntax

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

My xpath for a html page is as follows:
    `//div[@id='contenttext']/form/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[position()=1 or position()=2]`

Now I am checking a string which is actually in 2nd column of table. i.e. `td[2]`. Along with it it can be at `td[1]`. Hence for both of it i need to evaluate as TRUE.
BUT the OR condition in along with `position()` function is not working somehow.
Can you please suggest to check the string at both positions of the table column?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: strange. have you tried `[position()<3]`?

Comment: So, do you want both the column values or only one of them?

Comment: assuming we are discussing webdriver, it is probably easier to query all the td elements to List<WebElement> and apply some java code to make the distinction.

Comment: `td[contains(., 'your text') and position() <= 2]` should work correctly.

Comment: Looks like the hirerachy which you have specified might not be recognized. Can you try something like this //div[@id='contenttext']//tr[11]/td[position()=1 or position()=2] Hope this works. Happy coding.

Comment: @SuhirdSingh This should work, are you sure that `//div[@id='contenttext']/form/table/tbody/tr[11]/td` returns something?

Comment: I think the position is not working because if that particular element found at `td[1]` it would not consider `td[2]`

Answer (score 0):

What i need to check is a String say "State" which i am expecting that the person might have written in `td[1]` or`td[2]` , both of which should be a taken as a right solution.